# Phishing Attack - Magento 1.9 - Too many Get method request for customer login page - Site Down

Tags: security, magento1.9.2.3, core-hacks, get, godaddy

The IP : 167.172.230.190 hit my customer login page too many hits makes my server down

Screenshot : https://snipboard.io/kde4fw.jpg

Notes : Custom login page captcha enabled, added that IP in IP Blocker from Cpanel as well as added Godaddy firewall also still the attack continues...

Any help thanks.

Comment: If you have block this ip then it should able to access the website, Please discuss with your server support team ask them to block this IP, they will help you.

Comment: @Nits Added this IP in IP Blocker from Cpanel as well as added Godaddy firewall also still the attack continues

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nginx you can only allow people who come through your website

```
location /login { 
      valid_referers server_names ~^.*\.enteryourdomainname\.com; 
      if ($invalid_referer)
      {         
         return 401;      
      }
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
 }
```

I am sure you can do this with apache and .htaccess file as well. If you are using Apache webserver